# How to query Min/Max values ​and date together in TimescaleDB(using time_bucket)

Tags: sql, timescaledb, minmax

I have a "sandbox" table with two related columns in a timescale database (postgreSQL 13.3, TimescaleDB 2.2.1).

```
+------------------------------------+
| time  | timestamp without time zone|
+------------------------------------+
| value | double precision           |
+------------------------------------+
```

A value is entered every second into this table. I can get the max and min values ​​from this table at 1 minute intervals with the following query.

```
 SELECT 
    time_bucket('1 minutes', time) AS stamp,
    MIN(value) AS minValue, 
    MAX(value) AS maxValue
 FROM sandbox
 GROUP BY stamp;
```

However, this query only knows the minimum and maximum values, not the time corresponding to those values. I'm looking for a query that corresponding to the min/max value. i.e. something like:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| stamp               | min_time            | minValue | max_time            | maxnValue |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2021-06-14 00:00:00 | 2021-06-14 00:00:02 | 0        | 2021-06-14 00:00:44 | 22        |
| 2021-06-14 00:01:00 | 2021-06-14 00:01:59 | 2        | 2021-06-14 00:01:43 | 19        |
| 2021-06-14 00:02:00 | 2021-06-14 00:02:32 | 5        | 2021-06-14 00:02:24 | 26        |
| 2021-06-14 00:03:00 | 2021-06-14 00:03:52 | 1        | 2021-06-14 00:03:54 | 42        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So the simplest way to do this is to use the `first`/`last` functions, but instead of using the time column to do your ordering, use the value column instead. So first ordered by value = min, last ordered by value = max:

```
 SELECT 
    time_bucket('1 minutes', time) AS stamp,
    MIN(value) AS minValue
    first(time, value) AS minTime, 
    MAX(value) AS maxValue,
    last(time, value) as maxTime
 FROM sandbox
 GROUP BY stamp;
```

This can also be extended to multiple columns like so:

```
SELECT (mins).time as min_time, (mins).value as min_value ... (maxes).time as max_time ....
FROM (SELECT 
    time_bucket('1 minutes', time) AS stamp,
    first(s, value) AS mins,
    last(s, value) as maxes
 FROM sandbox s
 GROUP BY stamp) bookends;
```

You can also use something like `(mins).*` to get all of the columns out, but then they'd have the same names as the original columns and they'd be repeated, so you may need to alias each of them individually this way.

Comment: It works correctly. I tried a complicated way using the Join statement, but I couldn't think of how to use First()/Last(). Thank you.